# A Jim for all seasons

Tags: discussion

**Note: This contest is currently inactive. It may be resumed again in the future.**

So there has been a recent influx of new Jims (meaning maybe 2 in a while). Now, we all know that I am the one true Jim, lord of all other Jims, but nonetheless it gets confusing when someone pings Jim and Jim gets pinged as well.

But that's just extra fluff. As supreme leader of the kingdom of Jims, I'm offering, as a diplomatic envoy to the rest of Physics.SE, the chance for us to decide the title of Jims' fearless leader.

Here is the appropriate setting. Suggest your new name, something with Jim in it, and everyone will vote on it. The most popular name will be my new identifier each month for twelve months. One whole year *[insert subtle reference to the appropriateness of the title here]*. After that, I will step down and resume my title of Jim (unless a public outcry keeps me in office). If another name rises to be the most popular, I'll switch to that name for the remaining time.

I'll make some suggestions to give you an idea of what is possible. Be creative or don't, *so long as it's clearly a **Jim** name* (i.e. has "Jim" in it; "James" doesn't count).

Oh yeah, this post isn't strictly on-topic for meta. But it's a chance to have some fun. Close it if you must (but if you're name is Jim, be prepared to face the wrath of your king).

---

Important update: It seems I can only change my display name once a month. So each month I'll switch to the new most popular (if it changes so far in the future).

---

The first winner was: **Jimnosperm**

The second winner was: **ACuriousJim**

The third winner was: **Jim the Enchanter** (with a nice profile pic)

The fourth winner was: **Jims Bond**

The fifth winner was: **Jimself** (by a technicality)

The next name change (if it happens) will occur whenever I'm convinced to start this up again. After that, all answers will be edited to allow votes to be changed if so desired. At present, my name is going to remain as **Jim** while this is dormant.

Comment: While you're at it, why don't you add a snazzy profile picture? It doesn't have to be your face, unless the surface of your face has vanishing first Chern class :)

Comment: @JamalS Not a bad idea. Perhaps that could be another thing to vote on.

Comment: @JimdalftheGrey (for now) I don't think this has much of a chance of being closed as off-topic, since John Rennie posted on it (basically tacit approval from the King of Physics...)

Comment: @DaveCoffman I'm sure John appreciates the sentiment, but I'd say he's not so much the end all be all or king of physics, he's more the best individual representation of both the enthusiastic spirit of and the 1/\sqrt{2} mean total knowledge base from our regular users

Comment: @DaveCoffman: I just answer more questions than anyone else and the law of averages means some of the answers have to be correct :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie While saying that you answer more questions than anyone else is technically accurate, it still feels like a gross understatement. Plus the law of averages says some would be wrong, and very few of your answers are wrong (or even insufficient)

Comment: @ACuriousJim: To count the proposals that are months old defeats the purpose, of course. Each new one will have a very hard time beating e.g. the one that got 11 or 10 votes in February.

Comment: @NikolajK I edit the answers every time I update so that people can retract votes, change votes, etc. To give new names a fighting chance

Comment: "Jims Bond" seems to have overtaken "Jim the Encanter".

Answer (score 14):

Jimnosperm (not that I wish to start any rumours).

Will that do as a tree level approximation?

It's just been pointed out to me that [Jimnosperm's have light¹ cones](http://nurturestore.co.uk/pine-cone-math-station)!

---

¹ 10-100g depending on the species

Comment: Sigh. [Explaining bad jokes just makes them worse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnosperm) :-)

Comment: I wish I could vote you up once more for the "tree level approximation".

Comment: A Jim is never too off-topic. Nor is he not off-topic enough. He is precisely as far removed from the topic as he means to be.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals Am I missing something? Why have you copy-pasted my comment under Jimdalf here?

Comment: @Jimnosperm No. I copied and pasted it here because it sounds very off-topic.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals Yes I am definitely missing something. Do you mean this answer is off-topic? As an answer to the question, it is perfectly suitable. Did you mean the question overall seems off-topic? If so, that was the point of my original comment. I just made the comment under Jimdalf where it was most appropriate. Did I miss a whole bunch of now-deleted comments that led up to your posting that? Jim is so confused

Comment: @Jimnosperm No. Just the sperm part is off-topic.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals There is no "sperm part". A gymnosperm (all one word) is a type of plant.

Comment: @Jimnosperm Oh! I never knew that!

Comment: @FollowMyProposals Thus the "tree level approximation" and "they have light cones"

Comment: @Jimnosperm OK then.

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't catch on till reading the link and subsequent comments that Jimnosperm is not referring to "sperm" but to "gymnosperm".

Comment: @Cicero: maybe ... :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie lol 

Answer (score 13):

Sweep all before you

JimJimjeree

and next month it could be...

JimJimjeroo

Comment: Damnit, Rob! Now I'm *singing*! And it's your fault!

Answer (score 12):

Jimself

Answer (score 12):

I'm surprised nobody suggested... Jims Bond.

Answer (score 11):

Jim the Enchanter.

[image]

I think this would have to be my profile pic if this name is chosen

Comment: There are some who call me..... Jim

Comment: Please stop rotating now. This deserves to be permanent!

Comment: ... the pic, not necessarily the name! (just in case you were wondering :P )

Comment: @TheDarkSide That's not up to me

Comment: But it is! You can stop rotating at any time you wish. Or when you find the pic and name that suits you the most :P

Comment: @TheDarkSide It's up to the citizens of Jimistan. If they want their leader to have a different title, who am I (other than their supreme and all-powerful leader) to disagree?

Answer (score 11):

I will also suggest "The Jim".

Comment: A simple definite article. I like it. Am I even allowed to vote on answers though?

Comment: Well I certainly can't vote on it.

Answer (score 10):

I propose *ACuriousJim*.

Answer (score 9):

Jimdalf the Grey

Comment: A Jim is never too off-topic. Nor is he not off-topic enough. He is precisely as far removed from the topic as he means to be.

Comment: The battle for Jim's current username is over; the battle for Jim's *next* username is about to begin.

Comment: There is only one Lord of the Jims. Only one who can bend them to his will. And he does not share power

Comment: If more of us valued physics and mathematics and science above publishing priority, it would be a merrier world.

Comment: This name shall not pass!

Answer (score 9):

Jim Rennie, the first disciple of [the one and only](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1325/john-rennie)

Answer (score 8):

|JimUp>+|JimDown>.

However, each time someone pings you in chat you have to collapse to either |JimUp> or |JimDown> for the rest of the session :P

Comment: And some nerd will stop by this post and say it is not normalized! But $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left( \vert{\rm JimUp}\rangle + \vert{\rm JimDown}\rangle \right)$ will be bad for a username!!!

Comment: Did you know 〈 and 〉 do exist in unicode? Makes this even sexier.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I usually define \bra and \ket macros at the top of my Physics.SE answers if I'll need them. Makes this *even sexier*.

Comment: @Daniel You probably can't do that in a comment ping, though. I've got explicit 〈 and 〉 links from my keyboard, and they (amazingly and somewhat worryingly) do work inside mathjax - much simpler than explicit macros. So :P / ;).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty touche. Double :P to you.

Answer (score 5):

Flip it!

**ɯᴉſ**

Can be hard to ping, but who cares. It's *awesome*

Comment: Really is. How did you type it anyways?

Comment: _Can be hard to ping_. Well, it does solve the problem :P

Comment: @The, ˙[**ɯoɔ˙ʇxǝ┴uʍopǝpᴉsd∩**](http://www.upsidedowntext.com/) pǝsn I 'ʎllɐǝɹ oN ˙(: ɯǝlqoɹd ou 'ʇuɐʍ I ɟᴉ uʍop ǝpᴉsdn ʇᴉ ǝdʎʇ uɐɔ I

Comment: Hooray! Cool people from other SEs are partaking in this fun diversion too! And that was definitely the plan.... It is not my intention to slowly make myself known as the one true leader of all Jims across the SE network (I don't know where *that* idea came from). I am only interested in having fun and letting everyone else have fun too *[he said, nonchalantly]*

Answer (score 5):

Jim Moriarty
http://bakerstreet.wikia.com/wiki/Jim_Moriarty

Answer (score 5):

How about

> Jimtrinsic

where jimtrinsic qualities are the Jim-like qualities every Jim inherently possesses?

Comment: But then, every Jim deserves to be Jimtrinsic, no?

Answer (score 4):

Jimnasium

(play on [gymnasium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gym))

Comment: Possibly, Coach or even Head Coach of Jimnasium. But that's for others to decide

Comment: Also [Gymnasium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnasium_(Germany)).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I like that definition. Go Germans!

Answer (score 4):

Jimothy

[good reference here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtXxkXGK1rQ)

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who have been on StackOverflow:

"Jim Skeet"

Answer (score 4):

The Jimtimidator is another option...

Answer (score 3):

What about

Jim.

(with the period spoken explicitly, as "Jim - Period!"

Answer (score 3):

Jiminy Cricket, for a childhood throwback.

Answer (score 3):

How about LEEEEROY JIMKINS for a name?

Comment: I am curious about the reasoning. (says TheCuriousDarkSide) :P

Comment: Is it's being a meme not reason enough? ;p Or prehaps @jimnosperm is a total bad-ass.

Answer (score 3):

Invert it.

**MIJ**

Since the central problem was

> it gets confusing when someone pings Jim and Jim gets pinged as well

This will work unless one of the other Jims also lands up on this post! This is because there is no uniqueness theorem for usernames on the site, so MIJ's already taken doesn't mean it can't be taken again. But I guess that holds for every single of the suggestions above and below.

---

As an aside -

I think inverted usernames are employed on this site. e.g. inverting [yuggib](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50546/yuggib) gives bigguy, which makes sense as a username!

Comment: Why is it impossible for the other Jim to just be "Jim"? That's definitely possible and there actually are other "Jim"s currently

Comment: @Jimnosperm - But how? (I mean _just_ Jim, not guys like Jiminion.) e.g. if there is one guy named "The Dark Side", if another user signs up and tries to call himself exactly "The Dark Side", the system will (_should_) object. (Actually I don't know, I am only hoping it does, to prevent an identity crisis.) Am I wrong here?

Comment: No, the system doesn't object. In fact, Jiminion and I both changed our names originally because we were both Jim at the same time

Comment: @Jimnosperm You beat me by 13 seconds. I searched for Jim and many just Jims came out. Sorry, my plea is incorrect. I'll edit accordingly. :)

Answer (score 3):

Jimulhu

A recognition of Jim being part of the great Cthulhu diaspora

Comment: ph'nglui mglw'nafh Jimulhu Canadia wgah'nagl fhtagn

Comment: @ACuriousMind Like the Canadia. Nice touch

Answer (score 3):

Jimbiwan Kenobi

<sub>The Jim is strong with this one</sub>

Answer (score 2):

How about,"Lord Jim"? .........

Answer (score 2):

Jimperator

<sub>Perhaps [the most apt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/imperator) title for the leader of Jims</sub>

Comment: Until his tragic fall and complete destruction, of course....

Comment: The Jimperial army would never allow our great Jimpire to fall. And as our Jimperator; leader of the many Jimizens (as well as any wishing to Jimmigrate), that means they would never allow me to fall (and they really can't Jimpeach me with this system of government in place)

Answer (score 2):

Jimronimo - this is my proposal

Answer (score 1):

How about Jimmy Dodger - a play on "Jammy Dodger" which is a word with many meanings. Including a delicious biscuit that's a favorite (or favourite?) of the Doctor.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few:

Earthworm Jim

Slim Jim

Jimiroquai

Comment: You should probably make each name a separate answer. Otherwise, which do I use if this gets voted most popular?

Comment: I want to up vote Jimiroquai... but I cant.... please split these as pointed out by @JimdalftheGrey

Comment: +1 for Earthworm Jim.

Answer (score 1):

> Jimeese.

You see, it's Jim and cheese combined.

I like cheese, and I'm sure you do too.

---

I just thought of this.

You could simplify Jimeese into:

> Jeese.

or

> Jeez.

If you want.
But as the owner of this thread said, Jimeese sound more like Jim language.

Comment: Jeese and Jeez would be invalid as they don't have a full "Jim" in them. Also, I'd like to mention that Jimeese sounds like the language of the Jims

Comment: @JimdalftheGrey OK then. Use Jimeese.

Answer (score 1):

Jim_me_boy (hawkins) with pirate accent

Answer (score 1):

> Suggest Jim then. If it's most popular, who am I to argue –  Jim Feb 11 at 17:52 [[source](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6510/a-jim-for-all-seasons?page=1&tab=votes#comment24160_6514)]

Jim

Comment: Bonus points for obeying the commands of your supreme leader

Answer (score 1):

Jim Joyce.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[JIM mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIM_mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

How about Jim "your surname". I've noticed that most people seem to be satisfied with that as an identifier.

Comment: That said, you could suggest a surname

Comment: If you don't want to be easily identified, then I recommend keeping your name as Jim, and encouraging as many other "Jim" usernames as possible.

Comment: I see your point. But that's not as fun. Plus distinguishing me among Jims does not help one to identify me in the real world

Comment: Having lots of people called Jim sounds like fun to me

Comment: Suggest Jim then. If it's most popular, who am I to argue

Comment: [MO's take on the benefits of using your real name](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/204/20729). Obviously Mark and I agree on this one, but then again there are reasons not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Jim Post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/9789/tim-post). To get rid of the multiple-Jims confusion and replace it with confusion for those who have no idea who Tim Post is.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: [Jimbo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt6kKhlX8vU)

Answer (score 0):

Jimb.   The b is silent.  And pronounced like "climb" instead of "limb".

Answer (score 0):

[Gator's girls use jimmies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386588/)

Answer (score -1):

Dread Pirate Jimbeard

Answer (score -1):

Jimius Caeser, leader of the Holy Roman Jimpire (or just Jimius Caesar) because, as you say:

> But all you should be concerned about is that Jimius Caesar, leader of
>   the Holy Roman Jimpire, is commanding you to grant him additional
>   powers. You now have two options. Obey him, or face his wrath. - [Moderator nomination](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-282705)

Answer (score -3):

I went with Jiminion, and I'm stuck with it for a month.

Answer (score -5):

High King of Jimtopia

Comment: Jimtopia stole all their visuals from "The Phantom Jim".  Oh wait, it was the other way around.

Comment: Why the downvotes?